# Defining a new outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

let $(X,\Sigma, v)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. i.e., any set in $\Sigma$ can be represented by a countable union of sets whose measures are finite.

now, define $\mu^*(A):=\inf\{v(B)|A\subseteq B, \forall B\in\Sigma\}$. I want to show this set function is an outer measure.

that is, I want to show it has the properties listed below:

i) null empty set: $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$,

ii) monotonicity: $A_1\subseteq A_2\implies \mu^*(A_1)\leq\mu^*(A_2)$,

iii) countable subadditivity: $\mu^*(\cup A_i)\leq\sum \mu^*(A_i)$.

the first property follows immediately the fact that $v$ is a measure and $\emptyset\in\Sigma$.

but for the second and third, I can't treat the $\inf$ rigorously. like, for ii), I know that $A_2\subseteq B\implies A_1\subseteq B$, but can't deduce $\inf\{v(B)|A_1\subseteq B\}\leq \inf\{v(B)|A_2\subseteq B\}$ from it. intuitively it looks obvious, but every time I write the proof I can't stop thinking that I skipped something and it's not rigorous(in analysis, in general).

so, can you prove them as rigorous as possible? I would really appreciate.

Comment: By definition of $\mathrm{inf}$, to prove $\alpha \le \mathrm{inf} S$, it suffices to show $\alpha \le \beta$ whenever $\beta \in S$.  Now apply this with $\alpha := \mathrm{inf} \{ \nu(B) | A_1 \subseteq B \}$ and $S = \{ \nu(B) | A_2 \subseteq B \}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (ii), if $ U_2\subset U_1\subset [0,\infty]$ then $\inf U_1\leq  \inf U_2.$

If $A_1\subset A_2 \subset X,$ then for $j\in \{1,2\}$ let  $V_j=\{B:A_i\subset B\in \Sigma\}$ and let  $U_j=\{v(B):B\in V_j\}.$ We have $U_2\subset U_1$ because $V_2\subset V_1.$

For (iii): Let $A$ be a countable family of subsets of $X.$ If $A$ is infinite let $A=\{a_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ where $m\ne n \implies a_m\ne a_n.$ If $A$ is finite, with $k-1$ members (with $k\in \mathbb N$),let  $A=\{a_n:n<k\}$, and let $a_n=\phi$ for $n\geq k.$ This is to treat all cases (finite or infinite $A$) at once.

Observe that since $\mu^*(\phi)=0,$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu^*(a_n)=\sum_{a\in A}\mu^*(a).$

For $r>0,$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$ let $a_n\subset b_{n,r}\in \Sigma$ such that $\nu(b_{n,r})\leq r\cdot 2^{-n}+\mu^*(a_n).$  We have $\cup A=\cup_na_n\subset  \cup_nb_{n,r} \in \Sigma.$ Therefore $$\mu^*(\cup A)\leq v(\cup_nb_{n,r})\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}v(b_{n,r})\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(r\cdot 2^{-n}+\mu^*(a_n)\;)=r+\sum_{a\in A}\mu^*(a).$$ $$\text {Therefore } \quad \forall r>0 \;\left( \mu^*(\cup A)\leq r+\sum_{a\in A}\mu^*(a)\right).$$

Comment: sorry for the late response. I have one question about your answer: how are you sure that there is such $b_{n,r}$ for each $n$ and for every $r>0$? since $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, if we take a union of $a_n$ with some element $b$ of $\Sigma$, then we can find an element $c=a_n\cup b$ of $\Sigma$ such that $a_n\subseteq c$. but how do you know there is a proper $b$ making $c$ satisfy $v(c)\leq r2^{-n}+\mu^*(A_n)$?

Comment: By def'n of $\mu^*,$ for every $x>0$  there exists $b\in \Sigma$ such that 
 $b\supset a_n$ and $\nu(b)\leq x+\mu^*(a_n). $...... BTW. Two days to respond, on this site, I have learned to regard as a quick response.

Comment: I had written $\mu(b_{n,r})$ when it should have been $\nu(b_{n,r}).$

Comment: does the $\inf$ guarantee the existence of such $b_{n,r}$, right? these $\inf,\sup$ things, I never get used to them. thank you for your quick response btw.